# Why is my image moving down as I put more DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm busy trying to make a website, and I occurred this problem several times. When I add my DIV, my other div slides down! How can I prevent this from happening? 
I'm inexperienced so please take it easy.

CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gewoon Boef</title>
<style>

body {
background-color: black;
overflow: hidden;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 35px;
}

.image {
position: absolute;
right: 645.5px;
}

#boxes {
margin-top: 250px;

}

.box {
height: auto;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
border: 1px solid Green;
border-radius: 75px;
position: absolute;
left: -255px;
}

.box2 {
height: auto;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
border: 1px solid Green;
border-radius: 75px;
position: absolute;
left: -255px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="boxes">
<div class="box">kaas</div>
<br><div class="box2">Over Boef</div>
</div>
<center><img class="image" src="http://fakka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Capture105.jpg">
</center>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var main = function() {
$('.image').click(function () {
$(this).animate({
right: "-700px"
}, 1000);

$('.box').animate({
      left: "835px"
    }, 1000);

$('.box2').animate({
      left: "835px"
    }, 1000);

});
};
main();
$(document).Ready(main);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `position:fixed;` so it doesn't move or use a non-relative positioning attribute, otherwise it is relative to the other divs on the page.

Comment: It doesn't help me

Comment: how about telling where and how you add your div, what id or class it has etc. Without that info it's only guesswork.

Comment: I don't understand you, yezzz. If I think I do;
I would like to add a interactive menu  for when you click the image. The menu's are the two boxes, .box and .box2. It was working good until I added the #boxes ID. What I used to set the default margin-top.

Comment: divs by default stretch to the 100% of parent width. Try to add `display: inline-block;` to your divs style and they will align. If thats what you wanted

Comment: first thing to do - put your link to your jquery in the head of the document, not the body

Comment: I would start with not using the `<center>` tag as it's depreciated. Then move onto the difference between inline and block level elements.

Comment: You are not adding  any div's, they already exist. You are just animating them. Tell us what's the end result you want.

Comment: http://rachelgallen.com/help2.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one. Add a "Top" style. Right now, your code doesn't know where to place your div's vertically.

```
.box {
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid Green;
  border-radius: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -255px;
  TOP: 10px;  <---- ADD THIS.
}
```

Also, don't use half pixels.

Comment: And how do I prevent using half pixels? For more precision?

Comment: You cannot be more precise than a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `display:block` to `display:inline-block`. The fact that you defined a width will make several line up in a row.

Answer (score 0):

your element with the id "boxes" needs space so it pushes down it's next element `<center>`

to prevent this behaviour position your `id="boxes"` element and/or your `<center>` element absolute like this:

```
#boxes,
center {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put `position: fixed` in my `#boxes`. This made the image appear on it's original place. Thank you all for your help. My solution may not be a good solution, and may cause other problems in the future, but it's the only way I could solve it at the moment.